# install docker on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS

Tags: docker

I am trying to install docker-engine on my ubuntu desktop 14.0.4 LTS by following this:
[docker install url](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/)

Failing at step #11(apt-cache policy docker-engine)

```
root@ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook:/home/ashu# apt-get purge lxc-docker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'lxc-docker' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
root@ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook:/home/ashu# apt-cache policy docker-engine
docker-engine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.1-0~trusty
  Version table:
     1.9.1-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.9.0-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.3-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.2-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.1-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.0-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.7.1-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.7.0-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.6.2-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.6.1-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.6.0-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1.5.0-0~trusty 0
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

It's 500 error though when i visit this location[docker distribution](https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/)

I can see some of files...should i go ahead and install directly from there? Any suggestions based on your past experience?

```
root@ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook:/home/ashu# uname -r
4.2.5-040205-generic
```

I am using linux kernel 4.2.5
**Essentially installing docker didn't work, any help?**

Comment: You install packages through the terminal by running `sudo apt-get install packagename`. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I just followed that link to install docker. "sudo apt-get install docker" does install docker but that doesn't work.

Comment: you searched for `docker-engine`. Saying that installing docker didn't work might be a good thing to include in your question ;)

Comment: Try running "sudo apt-get install docker-engine" and see what happens. I succesfully installed docker from the same repo a few hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when it was getting stuck with the step#11. I went ahead with the remaining steps and was able to install it finally.

Answer (score 1):

***!!! Remember always backup before installing / purging etc !!!***

This were my installation steps on 16.04 (until 13<sup>th</sup> after that I installed also a 12.04 machine):

1.`sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates`

2.`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D`

3.`sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

4.`sudo su`

a.`echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

b.`exit`

5.`sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

6.`sudo apt-get update`

7.`sudo apt-get purge lxc-docker`

8.`sudo apt-cache policy docker-engine`

9.`sudo apt-get update`

10.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-`(uname -r)`
```

11.`sudo apt-get update`

12.`sudo apt-get install docker-engine`

13.`sudo service docker start`

14.`sudo docker run ubuntu:12.04 cat /etc/issue`

15.`sudo cat /etc/issue`
 #alternatively you can use:

16.`sudo docker pull ubuntu:12.04`
 #and then run that image

17.`sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:12.04 /bin/bash`
 #verify with

18.`cat /etc/issue`
 #ps don't forget to commit the changes, before exiting, otherwise are lost. 
First get the container id using this command:

19.`sudo docker ps -l`
 #commit changes to the container:

20.`sudo docker commit <container_id> repo/img1` 
 #then run in that container:

21.`sudo docker run -i -t repo/img1 /bin/bash`